# /scan is published, but /map is not

Tags: slam, ros-humble, nav2, turtlebot3

I am trying to run a multi-agent robot swarm using physical TurtleBot3's, with ROS2 Humble. I'd like to use Nav2 and SLAM Toolbox to navigate and map an area. I'm also interested in map merging, so I've been basing my work off of this [repo](https://github.com/robo-friends/m-explore-ros2). I've been able to run a multi-robot simulation with no problems. Now that I'm transitioning to real robots, though, I've run into problems with the cost map. I'm running each TurtleBot3 in it's own namespace according to the discourse [here](https://discourse.ros.org/t/giving-a-turtlebot3-a-namespace-for-multi-robot-experiments/10756), and launching independent stacks for each robot including Rviz, Nav2, and SLAM Toolbox. When complete, the only non-namespaced topic is /odom, although each robot has its own /odom topic as well.

The problem arises after launching: despite each robot's /scan topic always having values, it varies between runs whether each robot can generate a /map. Even when the /map topic is published, it seems to only do so once, and then the same problem arises. This causes a host of follow on issues. Looking at SLAM Toolbox, it looks like the only external topic it subscribes to is /scan. What might be happening to cause this behavior? I can even see the scans in Rviz, but the /map never loads.

I primarily get the error `Can't update static costmap layer, no map received`